# XSODATA service authentication in SAP HANA (XSA)

Tags: node.js, odata, hana, xsodata

I have exposed my table using xsodata. I can access it directly through the URL without giving username/password. How do I enable authentication for my xsodata service in SAP HANA (XSA) Web IDE?

Comment: By default you cannot access published service without authentication. Maybe you have some cookies or Kerberos authentication set up?

Comment: Very likely the session cookie from the WEBIDE session allows the access. A good workaround is to use incognito mode for testing or a different browser altogether.